# JProfile jpexport csv output missing headings

Tags: jprofiler

I'm evaluating JProfiler to see if it can be used in a automated fashion.  I'd like to run the tool in offline mode, save a snapshot, export the data, and parse it to see if there is performance degradation since the last run.

I was able to use the jpexport command to export the TelemetryHeap view from a snapshot file to a csv file (sample below).  When I look at the csv file I see 10 to 13 columns of data but only 4 headings.  Is there documentation that explains the output more fully?

Sample output:

"Time [s]","Committed size","Free size","Used size"

0.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
1.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
2.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
3.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
4.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
5.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
6.0,450,880,000,371,600,000,79,280,000
7.0,450,880,000,355,932,992,94,947,000
8.0,450,880,000,355,932,992,94,947,000
9.58,969,216,000,634,564,992,334,651,008
11.05,1,419,456,000,743,606,016,675,849,984
12.05,1,609,792,000,377,251,008,1,232,541,056
17.33,2,524,032,000,1,115,268,992,1,408,763,008
19.43,2,588,224,000,953,451,008,1,634,772,992
26.08,3,711,936,000,1,547,981,056,2,163,954,944
39.75,3,711,936,000,1,145,185,024,2,566,750,976
40.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,052,032,2,574,884,096
41.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,052,032,2,574,884,096
42.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,052,032,2,574,884,096
43.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
44.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
45.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
46.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
47.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
48.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
49.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
50.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
51.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
52.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
53.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
54.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
55.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
56.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
57.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
58.75,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
60.96,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
68.73,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120
74.39,3,711,936,000,1,137,051,008,2,574,885,120